# Define multiple html amd modules in one file

Tags: html, text, module, requirejs

Is there any way to do a requirejs define in a text document? Or an html document?

I have a document filled with header and cell templates for a grid

```
<body>
    <th data-fieldname="PatientPerson">Name <span data-bind="attr: { class: sortField() == 'PatientPerson' ? 'inline-block' : 'hide' }"></span></th>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-expand"></span><a data-bind="click: function () { $parent.loadReportSummary(PatientPerson.ID()) }"><span data-bind="text: PatientPerson.FullName"></span></a></td>

    <th data-fieldname="StudyType">Study Type <span data-bind="attr: { class: sortField() == 'StudyType' ? 'inline-block' : 'hide' }"></span></th>
    <td data-bind="text: StudyType"></td>


    <th data-fieldname="ServiceDate">Service Date<span data-bind="attr: { class: sortField() == 'ServiceDate' ? 'inline-block' : 'hide' }"></span></th>
    <td data-bind="text: ServiceDate"></td>


    <th>Export Summary</th>
    <td><a data-bind="click: function (data) { $parent.exportReportSummary(data, PatientPerson.ID, SummaryID, !StudyExported()) }">View</a></td>


    <th>Print All Reports</th>
    <td><a data-bind="click: function (data) { $parent.printAllReports('/PrintReports/Reports?summaryID=' + SummaryID) }">Print</a></td>

etc.......
</body>
```

In another module I have an array which determines which of these columns are used in a knockout computed observable. I was hoping that I could make each of these a module instead of parsing them using jquery, but I wanted them to all be in one file. I'm using the text plugin for requirejs, but there seems to be no way to declare each of these as a module inside of one file, and it seems wasteful to have to split each of these into separate files.

maybe something like

```
<!--export name:"PatientPerson" -->
    <th data-fieldname="PatientPerson">Name <span data-bind="attr: { class: sortField() == 'PatientPerson' ? 'inline-block' : 'hide' }"></span></th>
    <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-expand"></span><a data-bind="click: function () { $parent.loadReportSummary(PatientPerson.ID()) }"><span data-bind="text: PatientPerson.FullName"></span></a></td>
<!-- /export-->
```

Then referencing the module like

```
require('filename').PatientPerson;
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a plugin where you can add a !define to the end of the require on some file, and it will make the spec suggested from the OP work. It works with the official text plugin for requirejs.

```
define(['text', 'module'], function (text, module) {
    var exportRegExp = /<!--\s*?export[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<!--\s*?\/export\s*?-->/g,
    masterConfig = (module.config && module.config()) || {},
    buildMap={};
    text.export = function (content) {
        var exports = null;
        if (content) {
            var matches = content.match(exportRegExp) || [],
                match, _i, _len;
            exports = matches.length ? {} : null;
            for (_i = 0, _len = matches.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
                match = matches[_i];
                var exportName = match.match(/(<!--\s*?export\s*?name\:")(.*?)\"\s*?-->/).slice(-1)[0];
                exports[exportName] = match.replace(/<!--\s*?export[^>]*>\n?/, '').replace(/<!--\s*?\/export\s*?-->/, '');
            }
        }
        return exports;
    };
    var baseParseName = text.parseName;
    text.parseName = function(name) {
        var index, parseExport = false;
        index = name.indexOf('!export');
        if (index !== -1) {
            parseExport = true;
            name.split('!export').join('');
        }
        var out = baseParseName(name);
        out["strip"] = { "export": parseExport, "strip": out["strip"] };
        return out;
    };

    text.finishLoad = function (name, strip, content, onLoad) {
        var exports = strip.export ? text.export(content,name) : content;
        if (exports == null) content = strip.strip ? text.strip(content) : content;
        else content = exports;
        if (masterConfig.isBuild) {
            buildMap[name] = content;
        }
        onLoad(content);
    };
    text.write = function (pluginName, moduleName, write, config) {
        if (buildMap.hasOwnProperty(moduleName)) {
            var content = text.jsEscape(buildMap[moduleName]);
            write.asModule(pluginName + "!" + moduleName,
                           "define(function () { return '" +
                               content +
                           "';});\n");
        }
    };
});
```

The following will work

```
require([text!somefile!define],function(){})
```

This also works but it ignores the !strip command if any exports exist in the file.

```
require([text!somefile!strip!define],function(){})
```

then you can call

```
require(['someModuleNameInDefineComment'],function(){})
```

I have not handled strip with a beginning define in the header.

[Here is a Gist](http://gist.github.com/DrSammyD/9060376)